# Struggling with proof of obvious statement regarding an inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

Given that $n_1(n_1-1)\leq n_2(n_2-1)$ for $n_1, n_2 \in \{1, ..., n\}$ is true. How can I prove that $n_1 \leq n_2$ must also be true?

I thought about saying if $n_1 \leq n_2$ than $n_1^2 \leq n_2^2$ and therefore $n_1^2-n_1 \leq n_2^2 - n_2$, but here I'm already using the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding, we get $n_1^2-n_1\leq n_2^2-n_2$.

Now we complete the square: $(n_1-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}\leq (n_2-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$. Rearrange to obtain $(n_1-\frac{1}{2})^2-(n_2-\frac{1}{2})^2\leq 0$.

By the difference of two squares factorisation, $(n_1-\frac{1}{2}+n_2-\frac{1}{2})(n_1-\frac{1}{2}-n_2+\frac{1}{2})\leq 0$, and so $(n_1+n_2-1)(n_1-n_2)\leq 0$.

Now, using the fact that $n_i\geq 1(\forall i\in\mathbb{N})$ we gave that $n_1\leq n_2$ from the second bracket, or $n_1+n_2\leq 1$ from the first, which is impossible.

Hence $n_1\leq n_2$ as we wanted to prove.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$n_1^2-n_1=(n_1-\frac 12)^2-\frac 14$$

Comment: Thanks, got it !

Answer (score 0):

Because $n_1+n_2-1 \ge1$ we have
$$0 \ge n_1(n_1-1)-n_2(n_2-1)=n_1^2-n_2^2 - (n_1-n_2)\\=(n_1-n_2)(n_1+n_2-1) \ge n_1 - n_2$$
Done. No need to complete square.